# Permission is only granted to system apps

Tags: java, android, permissions

i have a problem with one permission in android manifest.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS"></uses-permission>
```

I go to file settings editor inspections and what i check exactly. I check it all options and the problem remain.

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: "Can anyone help me ?" -- help you with what? Some of those permissions -- `WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS` at minimum -- can only be held by system apps. So, unless you are building your own custom ROM, or you are going to rely on rooted device users putting your app on the system partition, you cannot hold `WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you please have a better title and more detailed information in the content with your effort to solve the problem?