# Is there an API in Xamarin.Forms for setting Android system theme?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I've been programming Xamarin.Forms apps, and for a project I need to be able to set the system theme from C# code. Most search results are for changing the *app* theme, but I'm looking to change the *system* theme, can this be done?

Comment: No. Nor would I expect there to be. Changing system theme would affect ALL apps. Anything that affects all apps should be done by user, not by an app. Otherwise, user may not know what has happened, nor how to get back to the previous state.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve Thanks for the reply, I understand where you're coming from, however I've since found apps that use the WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS permission to implement this functionality. The entire premise of my app relies heavily on the system theme being able to be changed, so hopefully there's an API out there

Comment: The permission you mentioned seems can't be granted to your app because it can only be held by system apps. You can check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38999032/permission-is-only-granted-to-system-apps).